# How to pass more than one value within dispatch in redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using redux in my react native app to manage cart item when add and remove, so when i want to add item to cart i am using the following:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const addItemToCart = item => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TO_CART', payload: item })
```

and here is the button when it pressed the above dispatcher is triggered:

```
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { addItemToCart(itemData, total) }} >
              <Text style={{ ...FONTS.h5 }}>Add to cart</Text>
               <Icon
                     name="cart-outline"
                     size={25}
                     color={COLORS.black}
                      backgroundColor={COLORS.primary2}
    
                  />
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

so here i am passing `itemData, total` to dispatcher which should be passed to cart.
and the following is the reducers:

```
const initialState = []

const cartItemsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
            return [...state, action.payload]
        case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
            return state.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id !== action.payload.id)
    }
    return state
}

export default cartItemsReducer
```

So, what I want is that the two passed values to be received in cartscreen and in cart screen I did the following to check if both two values are received or not:

```
  cartItems = useSelector(state => state)
    console.log("cart item: ", cartItems)
```

but only get `itemData` and  `total` is not passed.

What I can do to make both two values are passed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing the second parameter to the dispatcher, as your dispatcher only intakes one argument

```
const addItemToCart = item => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TO_CART', payload: item })
```

If you wanna pass two parameters, then just modify your fn to

```
const addItemToCart = (item, total) => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TO_CART', payload: { item, total } })
```

And then in your reducer, instead of having `action.payload` you will have `action.payload.item, action.payload.total`.